# how can we feed both data time series and non time series data together in machine learning classification model

Tags: time-series

[image: Screen shot of dataset are below]

I have a dataset(IoT wearable dataset) composed of time-series and integer data; the objective of my task is to use the dataset for classification. Whilst current libraries in sktime accept multivariate time-series data as input, I do not believe they accept integer data. What would be the best practice in this case? I am currently considering converting the integer data time-series by repeating the integer value for the same number of increments as the other multivariate inputs, then applying random noise to the manufactured integer data that I converted to Timeseries- Can anyone comment on whether this is an appropriate method or if there are other more appropriate ways to approach the issue? Thanks in advance.'

Comment: Hi, please include a sample of your data and the approach you have tried. This will help the community in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need two backbones: for time series, use LSTM/GRU and for non-time series, use 1D CNN or Linear layers. Once you get the final embeddings from both of them, concatenate the embeddings and finally feed to the classification layer.